# What is meaning of "Apropos acknowledgements," at start of a phrase?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

> Apropos acknowledgements, I should first of all like to express my gratitude to my friend and colleague ...

This quotation came from a preface of a book. As far as I understand, from dictionaries I've consulted:

> apropos = at an opportune time

and

> acknowledgements = a declaration or avowal of one's act or of a fact to give it legal validity

But what is meaning the combined phrase "Apropos acknowledgements"?

Comment: Look up the other meanings of 'apropos'.

Comment: opportunely , to the purpose; concerning; by the way. but I'm cofusing about phrase.

Comment: [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apropos) has: **apropos**  ... prep.
With regard to; concerning: _Apropos our date for lunch, I can't go._  // I'd start your sentence: 'First, a few acknowledgements: I'd like to start by  expressing my gratitude to my friend and colleague ...'. 'Regarding acknowledgements' and especially 'Apropos acknowledgements' sound very starchy.

Comment: Hi @yorgun.  I want to invite you, and everyone commenting/answering/voting here, to participate in [this meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7916/13804)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *à propos* literally means "on that subject".  Presumably whoever started a sentence with "Apropos acknowledgements" had earlier acknowledged someone else and, while he was acknowledging people...

Answer (score 0):

The French phrase *à propos* made an unusually awkward landing in English, as the following four entries in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) indicate:

> **<sup>1</sup>apropos** *adv* {F *à propos*, lit.,to the purpose} (1668) **1 :** at an opportune time : SEASONABLY **2 :** by way of interjection  or further comment : with regard to the present topic
>
> **<sup>2</sup>apropos** *adj* (1686) : being both relevant and opportune {*apropos* comments} ***syn*** see RELEVANT
>
> **<sup>3</sup>apropos** *prep* (1879) APROPOS OF
>
> **apropos of** *prep* (1746) : with regard to : CONCERNING

So starting in 1668, we have sentences of the form "He argued apropos against the new anti-witchcraft statute." Then, as of 1686, we have sentences of the form "He made apropos arguments about the supposed buoyancy of witches." Then, by 1746, we have sentences of the form "Apropos of the continuing controversy over secret covens, he noted that a real witch would simply cast a spell clouding everyone's mind and then go undetected." And finally, by 1879, we have sentences of the form "Apropos the animal magnetism theory, he noted that Franz Mesmer had never actually proved the existence of 'magnetic fluid.'"

These definitions suggest that *apropos* has a wide range of use in English. What they don't indicate is that *apropos* also has to share space with *à propos*, which continues to appear fairly frequently in English texts. So we have *apropos* as an adverb, *apropos* as an adjective, *apropos* as a truncated preposition (short for *apropos of*), *apropos of* as a prepositional phrase, and *à propos* as either an adverbial phrase or a prepositional phrase. It's quite an array.

It seems to me that the intended meaning of *apropos* in the OP's sentence beginning "Apropos acknowledgments..." is the one that the *Eleventh Collegiate* gives for *<sup>3</sup>apropos*—namely "APROPOS OF," or (in other words) "with regard to : CONCERNING." Swapping that meaning into the original sentence, we get this:

> With regard to acknowledgements, I should first of all like to express my gratitude to my friend and colleague ...

which I take to be the intended sense of the part of the sentence reproduced above.